# How do I import multiple tasks from a XML in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task, import

I have all the tasks from a server in a XML file obtained using

```
schtasks /Query /XML ONE>C:\schedtasksBackup.xml
```

Now, I want to import all the tasks in another server. All the info explains how to import o create ONE task at a time, but not multiple tasks at the same time.

It's possible? Or do I need to split the file in multiple atomic tasks file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this code to split the xml and import the tasks one by one:

```
var taskXML = new XmlDocument();
taskXML.Load(@"d:\temp\schedtasksBackup.xml");
var batbody = new StringBuilder();

XmlNodeList tasks = taskXML.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("Task");

string strFileName = "d:\\temp\\Task";

for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Count; i++) {
    string onetaskXML = tasks[i].OuterXml;

    //Create the New File. With a little more extra effort
    //you can get the name from a comment above the task
    XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(strFileName + "_" + (i+1) + ".xml");
    batbody.AppendLine(string.Format("schtasks.exe /create /TN \"{0}\" /XML \"{1}\"", "Task " + (i+1) + " Name", strFileName + "_" + (i+1) + ".xml"));

    //Write the XML
    xw.WriteRaw(onetaskXML.ToString());
    xw.Close();

    // Write a bat to import all the tasks
    var batfile = new System.IO.StreamWriter("d:\\temp\\importAllTasks.bat");
    batfile.WriteLine(batbody.ToString());
    batfile.Close();

}
```

**Edit:** BUT, it wasn't so easy. I couldn't find why, but `schtasks.exe` gives `malformed XML error` importing the file. I have to import the files manually (hate it, but didn't have more time to spend on the issue)

Comment: This answer does not explicitly say whether `/XML ONE` or `/XML` was used to generate the XML file.  This might be related to the "malformed XML error".

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you want to use schtasks you need to make them atomic.  I would recommend that you use the new-task cmdlet in powershell if you want to schedule multiple tasks (or just want more granular options) see [PowerShellPack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerShellPack) if you do not already have the resource kit installed.